# rollback for webcontent version in liferay

Tags: java, versioning, liferay

when I make changes to a web content in liferay and publish it .. It saves as new version.. But How can I rollback to previous version.. suppose I edited a web content it saves as version 1.1.. I want to make version 1.0 as active without deleting version 1.1?

Answer (score 3):

You can just **expire** version 1.1 of the article. In Liferay, only the highest not-expired version of an article is published. In this case this will be 1.0.

Comment: it would be more convinient if you could jump directly to a specific older version instead of running it through one by one.

Comment: Also finding the "history" view in Liferay seems quite complex, why can you not access the history directly from the article view rather then from the list of articles.